# how to set form name directly on symfony3?

Tags: forms, symfony

There is a default option or method to set the form name that does not require to use the form factory?

i know that using the factory the form name is the first parameter like this:

```
$this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, XType::class);
```

but i wanna to see if there is any way like the old method getName() on the form

Thanks